# ubercart checkout review button position

Tags: 6, theming, ubercart

I use drupal 6 and ubercart 2.

I would like to change position of the checkout button on checkout/review page to the top or possibly to duplicate it (it is currently on the bottom of the page which is not very user friendly)
I found a function in uc_cart.pages.inc called

```
function theme_uc_cart_checkout_review($panes, $form)
```

Inside on the bottom I found the code for review button

```
$output .= '<tr class="review-button-row"><td colspan="2">'. $form
        .'</td></tr></table>';
```

However, moving the code above the table code, breaks whole page. (I tried this inside the .inc file, because adding the function inside template file, I got an error) What would be the correct way of achieving my task? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your better off targeting the checkout button via CSS than mess with ubercarts tables on checkout as the $form contains all of the other code which you would need to parse to extract the button and apply it somewhere else.

Just do a position: absolute on the button.

If your CSS isn't up to par, then I would parse the $form variable and preg_replace() it out. You'll need to have good regex skills to grab it.

Comment: Thank you, css positioning never came to my mind. That is enough for my needs.